# Show field in MS Access query without including it in the group by clause

Tags: group-by, ms-access-2010, aggregate

I'm working on a query that will eventually be used as the record source for a report.

I have a customers and orders table.  I want to show customer_id, order_id, and order_date in a query, but I only want to show data associated with the **earliest** order date for each customer.  Basically, I need to show the order_id field without including it in the group by clause.  If I include it in the group by clause, I get a lot more records than I want.  Based on my research, the code below will work in mysql, but not ms access.

Select customer.customer_id, order.order_id, min(order.order_dt)

From customer inner join order on customer.customer_id = order.customer_id

Group by customer.customer_id

I've tried grouping by order_id in a sub query and ordering by customer then date, then using the first function in the outer query.  Unfortunately, the first function doesn't work as advertised.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?  It should bring up the earliest orders by order date for each customer.  If there is more than one order on the earliest order date for a customer, all of those orders will be shown, though, so keep it in mind.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, o.order_id, o.order_dt
FROM customers AS c INNER JOIN (orders AS o INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_ID, MIN([order_dt]) AS MinOrder_dt FROM Orders GROUP BY customer_id)  AS d ON (o.Customer_ID = d.customer_id) AND (o.[order_dt] = d.MinOrder_dt)) ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id;
```

I am deriving a table with just the customer_id and the min order_dt and joining customers and orders to that to only bring up the oldest orders.